# How to create a state-specific drawable xml for a toggle RadioButton

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

When creating button drawables, I typically follow the following format to implement an "onClick" change of background:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/RESOURCE_FOR_CLICKED" /> 
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/RESOURCE_FOR_CLICKED" /> 
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/RESOURCE_NORMAL" /> 
</selector>
```

This works fine for me when I am creating traditional buttons as I want them to return to their original state once `onClick` is finished, and I don't have to implement any code.

However, this does not work for `RadioButton`s because I actually want their background drawable to be different in the non-pressed state once they have selected.

Are there XML attributes for states involving radio buttons that I should be aware of to implement this sort of thing? If not, do I have to manage the changing of backgrounds in code?

Comment: Yes, I can confirm it works as expected and beautifully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`android:state_checked` will let you specify a drawable for when a radio item is selected.

Comment: Excellent - that saves a lot of coding! And I guess while I'm at it, is there a similar attribute to conditionally change text color on the button itself? Can I just use the same syntax in the `colors.xml` file, or does that not work?

Comment: @jshin47: Yes, you can use a color selector with the same `state_` attributes.